# Installing ROS Kinetic on Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, ros

I tried to install ROS Kinetic on Denian Jessie with http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian and met a big problem for me. Maybe its not a very difficult for you to solve it, because I'm a bit noobie in linux. My problem is on the step, when i need to download and install package of kinetic-full: `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`. After enter I saw a message that I have several held packages. I tried sudo `apt-get install -f` but it didn't do anything for me. What magic I need to do next? I tried to install all this package depends like `ros-kinetic-desktop` and `ros-kinetic-perception` but they have simular problem in installation.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. Perhaps you are asking the impossible,
or using the unstable, some required
packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help you:

The packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full: Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it will not be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages.

apt-cache search ros-kinetic-desktop
ros-kinetic-desktop - A metapackage to aggregate several packages.
ros-kinetic-desktop-full - A metapackage to aggregate several packages.
```

Comment: You need to give some more information, e.g. what architecture are you using (it seems there are no binary packages for i386), and what is the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install give 0-0-0 result, uname -a tell following: Linux lab02-216-1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: how about `apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

Comment: ros-kinetic-desktop-full:
  Installed: (absent)
  Candidate:   1.3.0-0jessie-20161003-135620-0700
  table of versions:
     1.3.0-0jessie-20161003-135620-0700 0
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ jessie/main amd64 Packages

Comment: So just try to install them again, and post the output, preferably as an edit to your question, so the formatting can be kept.

Comment: I tried to install the same  packages repeadly, used apt-get/aptitude/synaptic. Always got the same error. Maybe it is a way to install the candidate version?

Comment: sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Done/Done/Done
The packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full: Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it will not be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages.

Comment: So please add this output to your question, formatted as code!

Comment: OK, so what does e.g. `apt-cache search ros-kinetic-desktop` tell you about the unmet dependencies?

Comment: that there are 2 packages and I tried to install them both. In the ros-kinetic-desktop installation I met the same problem

Comment: ah, this is also a meta-package, so how about ros-kinetic-perception?

Comment: I mean `apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-perception`?

Comment: it depends from 7 packages like: ros-kinetic-image-common/ros-kinetic-laser-pipeline and others. I have tried to install them 1 by 1, but met the all the same problem with held packages((

Comment: after `apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-perseption` I saw the absent message

Comment: mhm, did you update your available packages by running `apt-get update` in between? Did you type `perception` correctly?

Comment: yes, I updated and made a mistake only in the comment(( I tried to go deeper and run the following: `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-roscpp` but it showed the simular `held` mistake

Comment: Something is really weird on your machine, I just tried with a fresh jessie install in virtualbox and had no problems. Can you install other packages?

Comment: I did. You think that I need to reinstall debian?

Comment: Mhm, maybe carefully inspect /etc/apt/sources.list, and the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d?

Comment: But if reinstallation is an option for you, this should do the job, as I seem to be unable to help - anybody else here?

Comment: the first 1 contain only the list of basic link to jessie - I installed the system no so long before, the second is empty

Comment: see my updated and undeleted answer

Answer (score 0):

After issuing the following command

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

you should have a file

```
ros-latest.list
```

under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, containing

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main
```

Then `apt-get update` and install as described in your post.

Comment: there are no debian package on this server

Comment: Yes, I made it before asking the parent question, I have the simular string im ros-latest.list, my problem appeared after it

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: I will try to make something with that and if I'll find any way to solve this - I will write it here

Comment: I reinstall all system and understand why this truble appeared. I used python3 in all packages like rosinstall instead of python

Comment: What does rosinstall have to do with the Debian package dependencies?

Comment: I don't know. I think the problem was in python3 dependencies. In first time I tried to install using py3 everywhere